# Type Error in python recursive binary search problem

Tags: python, recursion, search, binary

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        left, right = 0, len(nums) - 1
        
        while left <= right:
            curr_ind = (right+left)//2
            print(nums[curr_ind + 1:len(nums)])
            if nums[curr_ind] == target:
                return curr_ind
            elif nums[curr_ind] > target:
                return search(nums[left:curr_ind], target)
            elif nums[curr_ind] < target:
                return search(nums[curr_ind + 1:len(nums)], target)
            
        return -1
```

I am getting Unhashable Type 'list' error in the second to last line.
I don't think I am using dictionary in this problem, but I am not sure why it is giving me this error.

Comment: Your two calls to `search` should be to `self.search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using recursion wrongly, try this:

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        left, right = 0, len(nums) - 1
        
        while left <= right:
            curr_ind = (right+left)//2
            print(nums[curr_ind + 1:len(nums)])
            if nums[curr_ind] == target:
                return curr_ind
            elif nums[curr_ind] > target:
                right = curr_ind - 1
            elif nums[curr_ind] < target:
                left = curr_ind + 1
            
        return -1
```

Comment: this solution is not recursive

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def bs(self, current:List[int], left: int, target: int) -> int:
        if len(current) == 1:
            return left if current[0] == target else -1
        index = len(current) >> 1
        if current[index] < target:
            return self.bs(current[index:], left + index, target)
        elif current[index] > target:
            return self.bs(current[:index], left, target)
        else:
            return left + index

    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        return self.bs(nums, 0, target)
```